# Kotlin - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

There is the XML layout

I past the [code](https://pastebin.com/HThz1ehg) in pastebin because it's too long

I'm Trying To build the tic tac toe game and It's work Perfectly but when I click the last button that it's will be in the row the The app Get  crush. it's work great but I don't know why it's give me this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ziadabouelfarah.tictactoy, PID: 6182
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.amin(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
        at com.agefinder.hell.MainActivity.autoPlay(MainActivity.kt:173)
        at com.agefinder.hell.MainActivity.PlayGame(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at com.agefinder.hell.MainActivity.buSelect(MainActivity.kt:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

And my code in Kotlin Is like the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }


    fun buSelect(view:View){
        val buSelected= view as Button
        var cellID=0
        when(buSelected.id){
            R.id.bt1-> cellID=1
            R.id.bt2-> cellID=2
            R.id.bt3-> cellID=3
            R.id.bt4-> cellID=4
            R.id.bt5-> cellID=5
            R.id.bt6-> cellID=6
            R.id.bt7-> cellID=7
            R.id.bt8-> cellID=8
            R.id.bt9-> cellID=9

        }
        // Toast.makeText(this,"ID:"+ cellID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        PlayGame(cellID,buSelected)
        Thread.sleep(500)
    }

    var player1=ArrayList<Int>()
    var player2=ArrayList<Int>()
    var ActivePlayer=1

    fun PlayGame(cellID:Int,buSelected:Button){

        if(ActivePlayer==1){
            buSelected.text="X"
            buSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pink)
            player1.add(cellID)
            ActivePlayer=2
            //Thread.sleep(500)

            autoPlay()
        }else{
            buSelected.text="O"
            buSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
            player2.add(cellID)
            ActivePlayer=1
        }


        buSelected.isEnabled=false
        CheckWiner()
    }



    fun  CheckWiner(){
        var winer=-1

        // row 1
        if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(2) && player1.contains(3)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(2) && player2.contains(3)){
            winer=2
        }


        // row 2
        if(player1.contains(4) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(6)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(4) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(6)){
            winer=2
        }




        // row 3
        if(player1.contains(7) && player1.contains(8) && player1.contains(9)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(7) && player2.contains(8) && player2.contains(9)){
            winer=2
        }



        // col 1
        if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(4) && player1.contains(7)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(4) && player2.contains(7)){
            winer=2
        }



        // col 2
        if(player1.contains(2) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(8)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(2) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(8)){
            winer=2
        }


        // col 3
        if(player1.contains(3) && player1.contains(6) && player1.contains(9)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(3) && player2.contains(6) && player2.contains(9)){
            winer=2
        }


        if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(9)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(9)){
            winer=2
        }

        if(player1.contains(3) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(7)){
            winer=1
        }
        if(player2.contains(3) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(7)){
            winer=2
        }

        if( winer != -1){

            if (winer==1){
                Toast.makeText(this," Player 1  win the game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this," Computer  win the game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

        }

    }

    //var buSelect:Button?=null

    fun autoPlay(){

        var buSelect:Button?=null

        val emptyCells=ArrayList<Int>()
        for ( cellID in 1..9){

            if(!( player1.contains(cellID) || player2.contains(cellID))) {
                emptyCells.add(cellID)
            }
        }


        val r=Random()
        val randIndex=r.nextInt(emptyCells.size-0)+0
        val cellID= emptyCells[randIndex]


        buSelect = when(cellID){
            1-> bt1
            2-> bt2
            3-> bt3
            4-> bt4
            5-> bt5
            6-> bt6
            7-> bt7
            8-> bt8
            9-> bt9
            else->{
                bt1
            }
        }

        //Thread.sleep(500)

        PlayGame(
            cellID,
            buSelect!!
        )

    }


}
```

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace, please?

Comment: @tynn I update the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling **Random.nextInt()** with zero and it throws

```sh
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
```

When your game ends i.e. when the last cell is clicked, all the cells will be consumed by both the player. So to avoid this error, simply add.

```sh
if(!emptyCells.isEmpty())
{
    val randIndex=r.nextInt(emptyCells.size-0)+0 
}
else 
{
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Could not execute method for android:onClick` also means, that something was wrong with the execution, meaning there was an exception thrown from your *onClick* listener.

In your case `r.nextInt(emptyCells.size-0)+0` is the culprit. The bound has to be positive, but `emptyCells` is empty and therefore `emptyCells.size` is 0.

You'd have to handle this case before. Eventually your game is finished anyway.

```
fun autoPlay(){
    var buSelect: Button? = null

    val emptyCells = ArrayList<Int>()
    for (cellID in 1..9) {
        if (!(player1.contains(cellID) || player2.contains(cellID))) {
            emptyCells.add(cellID)
        }
    }

    // if all cells have been checked, the game is over
    if (emptyCells.isEmpty()) return

    val r = Random()
    val randIndex = r.nextInt(emptyCells.size)
    val cellID = emptyCells[randIndex]

    buSelect = when(cellID) {
        1 -> bt1
        2 -> bt2
        3 -> bt3
        4 -> bt4
        5 -> bt5
        6 -> bt6
        7 -> bt7
        8 -> bt8
        9 -> bt9
        else -> {
            bt1
        }
    }

    //Thread.sleep(500)

    PlayGame(
        cellID,
        buSelect!!
    )
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand your answer very well can u explain more

Comment: It mean I can just put that line in try and catch statment